# Differences between Visual Studio Modes (General, Web Dev, C#)?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

what exactly are the differences between the different Visual Studio install modes (General, Web Development, C#)? This is also confusing because I do Web Development in C#. Which one should I use?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe it sets keyboard shortcuts, whats on the dropdown menus, what windows are open by default and maybe other options.

I'm not aware of the exact changes...

You can change this setting later, under Tools->Import and Export Settings... Selecting the Reset option in this dialog will let you choose one of the others.

EDIT: I found the [MSDN article listing the customizations for each of the settings here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zbhkx167.aspx).

Comment: Oh... and one more thing; I'm quite happy doing ASP.NET and C# with the C# settings...

Comment: A list of differences between the predefined keyboard shortcuts in various modes you may find here:    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/da5kh0wa(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

It changes the Intellisense according to the selected profile as well.